# Call a Runnable class inside an Activity

Tags: java, android, runnable

I've a Runnable class , Is it possible to call this runnable class inside an activity ?

Here is my class :

```
public class TstClass implements Runnable {

static boolean m_bret = false; 
static String m_szconfig = "-i";
private int n_stat;
public native String unimplementedStringFromJNI();


static {
    try {
        System.out.println ( "[AdDBCache] Module load try ffmpeg : " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary("tstjni");
        System.out.println ( "[AdDBCache] Module load success");

     } catch ( Exception e ) {
         System.out.println ( "[AdDBCache] Module load err : " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
}
}

private static synchronized final native int mod_run (String name, String sztoken );

public void set_config ( String sz_config ) {
    m_szconfig = sz_config;
}


public void run_core ( String sz_file, String sz_token ) {
    m_bret = false;
    n_stat = mod_run ( m_szconfig, sz_token );
    m_bret = true;
}


public void run () {
    run_core ("", "");
}

}
```

Logcat error:

```
03-14 17:53:11.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2605): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
03-14 17:53:11.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2605): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mod_run
03-14 17:53:11.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at com.parsapp.actionmovie.ffmpeg.mod_run(Native Method)
03-14 17:53:11.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at com.parsapp.actionmovie.ffmpeg.run_core(ffmpeg.java:31)
03-14 17:53:11.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at com.parsapp.actionmovie.ffmpeg.run(ffmpeg.java:37)
03-14 17:53:11.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following?
Did you encounter any problems?

```
TstClass tst = new TstClass();
new Thread(tst).start();
```

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: Thank you but when I use Thread I got an error which say Thread is undefended for the type of activity.

Comment: @iSun I'm sorry I forgot the `new` keyword before calling the `Thread` class. I updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: @iSun, I suggest you analyze the stack trace. You can share it with us if you want some help also.

Comment: @iSun, the code posted above is correct. You should accept his answer. I can tell you now that the force close is being caused by your own code. Likely from trying to load your library

Comment: Can you see my logcat please.

Comment: @iSun, what are you trying to accomplish with the `mod_run()` function?

Comment: well mod_run() is the Jni code , I read an article about ffmpeg and just according from following link :http://jameroid.tistory.com/entry/JNI-ffmpeg

Comment: @iSun since we're facing a new problem, I suggest you open a new question detailing the problem in order for it to gain visibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
new TstClass().run();
```

should be work . Have you tried?

Comment: and why it should be as you say?

Comment: @TiagoPasqualini could please explain why run a Runnable in the way I suggested does not work?

Comment: Since it's a Runnable class, you need to create a Thread for it to run simultaneously with another thread. Just calling run() it will run in the same thread, and not start another one.

Comment: @blackbelt, according to the docs, calling `run()` only executes the `run()` method once, it does not start a new thread.

Comment: @TelmoMarques I know, and actually he asked no for a new thread but ask to execute a runnable, am I wrong?

Comment: @blackbelt I'm guessing we understood different things from the same question.